# mySQL - Sorting techniques and ordering

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, rating

i have a table that contains a list of images and would like to sort them to a popular image sequence.
Below listed the table and i would like to make the "Target column", in order for me to sort popular image.

[image: sql_table]

Here is the SQL code:

```
SELECT imageID FROM  `ratings` WHERE rating > 3 ORDER BY imageID DESC
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what is the question? what is the input / expected output / actual output of your current approach?

Comment: The column imageID is the input, the target column would be the expected output

Comment: based on what algorithm???? `SELECT imageID, rating Target FROM ratings`?

Comment: sorry for unclear question, the target column aims to sort out popular image sequence order, if the image(10) listed most among all the imageID, then image(10) should be listed as 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, use a count and a group by, this will count repeated ImageID:

```
SELECT count(*) as ct, imageID  
  FROM `ratings` 
 WHERE rating > 3 
 GROUP BY imageID
 ORDER BY ct
```